# Heaviside with $(x^2-1/2)$ argument?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How to deal with the unit step function with an argument of $H(x^2-1/2)$ ? what does it equal to?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Heavisde%28x%5E2-1%2F2%29

Answer (score 2):

It's immediate from the definition of the Heaviside function that

$$H\left(x^2 - \frac 1 2 \right) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 1 & \text{if }x^2 - \frac 1 2 > 0 \\ 0 & \text{ else }\end{array}\right.$$

So look at where $x^2 - \frac 1 2$ is positive and negative.